# Why can't Saturn's rings be absorbed into the planet due to it's gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, orbital-motion, conservation-laws

What stops Saturn's rings from going into the planet?

Comment: The same thing that stops the earth from falling into the sun.

Answer (score 7):

Basically the rings don't fall into Saturn for the same reason the Moon doesn't fall into the earth.  The rings are billions of little moons, each in it's own stable, or largely stable orbit.   The rings are also likely resupplied with new ring material from Enseladus, Saturn's 2nd closest moon. (ice volcanoes due to strong tidal forces that can shoot ice into space), so, while the rings possibly lose some material over time, they also gain material.